# Is there a quicker way to remove top rows from multiple dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 19 dataframes that I am looking to make into one giant dataset.

```
dfs <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8, df9, df10, df11, df12, df13, df14, df15, df16, df17, df18, df19)

# columns renamed to common titles, so that all data can be binded properly

for (i in seq_along(dfs)){
  colnames(dfs[[i]]) <- colnames
}

# all datasets combined into one data frame

tidier_data <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, dfs)
```

This process works fine and brings all the data over perfectly, however, there is a problem that I am hoping can be solved. In each data frame, the top 7 rows are related to metadata that is not relevant for the analysis that I am doing, and once the data is binded together, the metadata is scattered around the whole document, where each `df` is being binded. Currently I am just manually removing the top 7 rows by using the following for `df1` to `df19`:

```
df1 <- tail(df1, -7)
df2 <- tail(df2, -7)
df3 <- tail(df3, -7)
df4 <- tail(df4, -7)
df5 <- tail(df5, -7)
df6 <- tail(df6, -7)
df7 <- tail(df7, -7)
df8 <- tail(df8, -7)
df9 <- tail(df9, -7)
df10 <- tail(df10, -7)
df11 <- tail(df11, -7)
df12 <- tail(df12, -7)
df13 <- tail(df13, -7)
df14 <- tail(df14, -7)
df15 <- tail(df15, -7)
df16 <- tail(df16, -7)
df17 <- tail(df17, -7)
df18 <- tail(df18, -7)
df19 <- tail(df19, -7)
```

Obviously this takes up a large number of lines, so I am trying to find a way to shorten the process. If there is any way to do this, please let me know, otherwise I will just have to do it all manually! Thanks :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

work with the list you already created:

```r
dfs <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8, df9, df10, df11, df12, df13, df14, df15, df16, df17, df18, df19)

dfs2 <- lapply( dfs, function(d) tail( d, -7 ) )

## rest of the code with dfs2
```

Comment: Ahhh true I thought lapply would work but couldn't figure out the exact syntax! Thanks Sirius

Comment: Could also do `lapply(dfs, tail, -7)`. +1

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

dfs <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8, df9, df10, df11, df12, df13, df14, df15, df16, df17, df18, df19)


dfs %>%
  map_dfr(., ~ slice(.x, -(1:7)))     # map_dfr() will automatically row bind all the outputs.
```